# How to subtract two columns from different tables and set result for the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to programming and I'm doing a project for myself to consolidate the material. I tried all the methods, but without success. How to correctly write a trigger that, after entering data in the second table in the MOVING_QUANTITY attribute, automatically subtracted SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY from the first table from MOVING_QUANTITY in the second. And the new result was already recorded in SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY. In other words, a replacement for the first. I wanted to implement an idea where, for example, I transfer a certain amount of goods and enter the quantity I need, and he took the quantity of a certain product from the warehouse table. Below I have given the tables, and my own trigger, but it does not work correctly as I wanted.

```
 CREATE TABLE Storage_Prod_List
 (
 STORAGE_PROD_ID     INT           PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
 FK_SP_STORAGE_ID    INT,
 FK_SP_PRODUCT_ID    INT,
 SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY    INT        NOT NULL
 );

 CREATE TABLE Moving_list
 (
 MOVING_ID           INT           PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
 MOVING_DATE         DATE         NOT NULL,
 MOVING_PRODUCT      INT,
 MOVING_QUANTITY     INT           NOT NULL,
 FROM_STORAGE        INT,
 TO_SHOP             INT,
 );


 CREATE TRIGGER UpdateQuantity
 ON Moving_list
 AFTER INSERT
 AS 
 BEGIN
    UPDATE st
    SET SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY = SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY - (SELECT MOVING_QUANTITY FROM  Moving_list)
    FROM Storage_Prod_List st
    JOIN (SELECT MOVING_ID, SUM(MOVING_QUANTITY) AS Quantity FROM INSERTED GROUP BY   MOVING_ID) i ON st.STORAGE_PROD_ID = FK_SP_PRODUCT_ID
 END;
```

I've been sitting here for days, but I can't think of anything.

The result I want to achieve:

| FK_SP_STORAGE_ID | FK_SP_PRODUCT_ID | FK_SP_PRODUCT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Storage-1 | Coco-cola | 500 |
| Storage-1 | Fanta | 500 |

| MOVING_PRODUCT | MOVING_QUANTITY |
| --- | --- |
| Coco-cola | 400 |
| Fanta | 400 |

Result:

| FK_SP_STORAGE_ID | FK_SP_PRODUCT_ID | FK_SP_PRODUCT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Storage-1 | Coco-cola | 100 |
| Storage-1 | Fanta | 100 |

Comment: It will be much easier for us to help you if you can provide some sample data and the expected result. Please do not use image, edit the question and include the data as text

Comment: What results do you get from your code?  Wrong result/error message or something else?

Comment: I added the result I want to get, please look @Squirrel

Comment: Look at the result above that I'm aiming for. It turns out that if I enter 400 pieces of Coca-Cola, then it should accordingly subtract from the amount of Coca-Cola in the Storage_Prod_List table. And as a result, it takes away this amount from other products too. Thank you @MartinCairney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the wrong column name in the trigger.

Your join condition is wrong. You are not joining to the column in `Moving_list` at all

```
ON st.STORAGE_PROD_ID = FK_SP_PRODUCT_ID
```

You are subtracting `SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY` with all `MOVING_QUANTITY` from table `Moving_list`. It will result in error when the `Moving_list` table contains more than 1 row

```
SET SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY = SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY 
                        - (SELECT MOVING_QUANTITY FROM  Moving_list)
```

The sub query should be group by `MOVING_PRODUCT` not `MOVING_ID`

```
GROUP BY   MOVING_ID
```

The corrected trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateQuantity
 ON Moving_list
 AFTER INSERT
 AS 
 BEGIN
    UPDATE st
    SET    SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY = st.SP_PRODUCT_QUANTITY 
                               - i.Quantity
    FROM   Storage_Prod_List st
    JOIN   (
               SELECT MOVING_PRODUCT, SUM(MOVING_QUANTITY) AS Quantity 
               FROM   INSERTED 
               GROUP BY MOVING_PRODUCT
           ) i ON st.FK_SP_PRODUCT_ID = i.MOVING_PRODUCT
 END;
```

Comment: Now I understand where I made a mistake, thank you very much. You made my day!